# UIWebView Zoom out pdf programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, uiwebview, zooming

**Default PDF view in UIWebView**

[image]

**I want to convert UIWebView to Display this much zoom by default for this PDF.**

[image: i want]

#### is it possible to do this for PDF?

Comment: WHY YOU ARE NOT RESIZING YOUR WEB VIEW, I THINK IT WILL SOLVED UR PROBLEM :) @hardik.shah

Comment: @sanjeet No i cant do that because i want user to allow Scaling and zooming with screen size